# Wiener measure of smooth function in space of continuous function.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, wiener-measure

How do we show that the Wiener measure of class of smooth functions in $C[0, \infty)$ is 1?

Comment: Do you mean $0$....?

Comment: Yes that is 0..